# Expanding width of a 2D tensor in Tensorflow, by repeating its columns

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, slice

I have a 2d tensor which must be expanded in the width (column number) direction. In the example below, I want to make B as wide as A by repeating its columns.

This can be done in numpy by:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8]])
B = np.array([[19,15],[18,14],[17,13]])

ncl = A.shape[1]

B = B[:,np.mod(np.arange(ncl),B.shape[1])]
print(B)
```

Yields:

```
[[19 15 19]
 [18 14 18]
 [17 13 17]]
```

How can I do this for two constant tensors A and B, in Tensorflow?

Comment: any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
A = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,6,4,5,6,7],[6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7]])
B = tf.constant([[19,15],
             [18,14],
             [17,13]])

diff = A.get_shape()[1] - B.get_shape()[1]

Bt = tf.transpose(B)
for idx in range(diff):
    col = tf.gather_nd(Bt, [[idx]])
    Bt = tf.concat(0, [Bt, col])

result = tf.transpose(Bt)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(result)
    print(res)
```

not the most beautiful code ever, but it works.

Output:

```
[[19 15 19 15 19 15 19 15]
 [18 14 18 14 18 14 18 14]
 [17 13 17 13 17 13 17 13]]
```